# UITextField don't change semantic in RTL iOS

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uitextfield, right-to-left

I have app with two language english and arabic (user will change language from app)

When I choose Arabic from edit schemes to test Right To Left UI, all working fine, but when I force RTL when user change language:

```
let semantic: UISemanticContentAttribute = (lang == "ar") ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceRightToLeft
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
```

All views are changed to RTL except UITextField even if I'm using leading and trailing constraints

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to Apple Document

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change
>   the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view
>   from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

The reason might be your textfieds are already in the current window. So let's try to replace your window when the language is changed or try to update `semanticContentAttribute` once your UITextField are allocated.

```
 self.textField.semanticContentAttribute = (lang == "ar")? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
```